# How can I plot multiple lines using the same array and set disconnect points in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

I have the following array of given shape:

```
print sph_pos_count.shape

(250,7)

print sph_pos_count[:3]

[[  30.            1.94421493    2.26455071  689.30568152  434.85076648
718.60031987  211.        ]
[  60.            1.94421493    2.26455071  671.44480704  456.32674497
707.65630274  160.        ]
[  90.            1.94421493    2.26455071  653.58393256  477.80272345
696.71228561  125.        ]]
```

I want to select data and plot lines. I am doing the following, however the lines are connected at the ends:

```
plt.plot(sph_pos_count[:,0], sph_pos_count[:,6], c = 'r', marker= '1')
```

[image]

How do make sure that the ends of lines are not connected to beginning points of subsequent lines?

Comment: the code and the picture you show doesn't match. show your real code

Comment: What do you mean? Could you show me what you get? By the way, the array is a numpy array and I have shown a snippet of it as the data is big. You can populate a general 2d array by: Zhu shows in the answer below.

Comment: If you `plot(a[:,0], a[:,6])` there should be just one line if `a` contains no `None`, but the figure you show has multiple lines

Comment: Or may I understand that you want to separate `sph_pos_count` by some special values?

Comment: Exactly! However the numbers repeat as you can see on the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your data, especially the last row, your code itself should work fine:

```
a=np.random.normal(size=(250,7))
a[:,0]=np.arange(250)*1.0
plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,6], c = 'r', marker= '1')
```

[image]

As expected, you have repeating values, so this should do the trick:

```
a=np.random.normal(size=(250,7))
a[:,0]=np.array(range(25)*10)
plots=[plt.plot(a[i*25:(i*25+25),0], a[i*25:(i*25+25),6], c = 'r', marker= '1') for i in range(10)]
```

Basically, plot one column in 10 segments.

[image]

Comment: Now in this code that you generated how can you set points to cut off the line? SO that you have multiple line segments?

Comment: A lazy way is just to insert some `nan` at the positions where you want a break.

Comment: It sounds like a good fix. However can you please point me to a direction where I could find another means to solve my problem?

Comment: Also, in my data, the x-axis repeats on a ranges between two numbers and subsequently repeats 25 times: there are 10 numbers in the range on axis.